Any research on ODE $\frac{1}{\sin ^{N-2} \theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}(\sin ^{N-2} \theta \frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta})=f(u)$?
I want to know if there is any research on ODE $$\frac{1}{\sin ^{N-2} \theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}(\sin ^{N-2} \theta \frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta})=f(u)$$
with any boundary condition?
Actually I'm studying $$\Delta u = f(u)$$ on the upper half sphere in dimension $N$, for example, if I want to study the radial symmetric solution which only depends on the distance to the north pole which is $\theta$ in spherical Laplacian

Then I can rewrite the ODE as
$$
\frac{1}{\sin ^{N-2} \theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left(\sin ^{N-2} \theta \frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}\right)=f(u)
$$
I know this ODE is complex but I still want to ask if there is any research on it.
Update: Sorry for my careless omission, I want to ask about the case when $f$ is nonlinear such as $$f(u)=e^u.$$ The tools I mastered are almost all about the elliptic PDE, so I have no idea about how to prove the existence of solution to nonlinear ODE, if you could recommend me some knowledge about the existence of solution to nonlinear ODE, I will be very glad!

Maple 2024 solves it for a linear function $f$:
restart;dsolve(diff(sin(theta)^(N - 2)*D(u)(theta), theta)/sin(theta)^(N - 2) = 
a*u(theta)+b, u(theta)) assuming (N::posint, 2 <= N));


u(theta) = sin(theta)^(-1/2*N+3/2)*LegendreP(1/2*(N^2-4*N-4*a+4)^(1/2)-1/2,-3/2 +1/2*N,cos(theta))*c__2+sin(theta)^(-1/2*N+3/2)*LegendreQ(1/2*(N^2-4*N-4*a+4)^( 1/2)-1/2,-3/2+1/2*N,cos(theta))*c__1+2*b*sin(theta)^(-1/2*N+3/2)*(LegendreQ(1/2 *(N^2-4*N-4*a+4)^(1/2)-1/2,-3/2+1/2*N,cos(theta))*Int(sin(theta)^(1/2*N-1/2)* LegendreP(1/2*(N^2-4*N-4*a+4)^(1/2)-1/2,-3/2+1/2*N,cos(theta))/(LegendreQ(1/2*( N^2-4*N-4*a+4)^(1/2)-1/2,-3/2+1/2*N,cos(theta))*LegendreP(1/2*(N^2-4*N-4*a+4)^( 1/2)+1/2,-3/2+1/2*N,cos(theta))-LegendreP(1/2*(N^2-4*N-4*a+4)^(1/2)-1/2,-3/2+1/ 2*N,cos(theta))*LegendreQ(1/2*(N^2-4*N-4*a+4)^(1/2)+1/2,-3/2+1/2*N,cos(theta))) ,theta)-LegendreP(1/2*(N^2-4*N-4*a+4)^(1/2)-1/2,-3/2+1/2*N,cos(theta))*Int(sin( theta)^(1/2*N-1/2)*LegendreQ(1/2*(N^2-4*N-4*a+4)^(1/2)-1/2,-3/2+1/2*N,cos(theta ))/(LegendreQ(1/2*(N^2-4*N-4*a+4)^(1/2)-1/2,-3/2+1/2*N,cos(theta))*LegendreP(1/ 2*(N^2-4*N-4*a+4)^(1/2)+1/2,-3/2+1/2*N,cos(theta))-LegendreP(1/2*(N^2-4*N-4*a+4 )^(1/2)-1/2,-3/2+1/2*N,cos(theta))*LegendreQ(1/2*(N^2-4*N-4*a+4)^(1/2)+1/2,-3/2 +1/2*N,cos(theta))),theta))/(N-(N^2-4*N-4*a+4)^(1/2)-4) 

Its $\LaTeX$ is too big to be presented here.
Addition. The modified ODE with $\exp(u(\theta))$ in the RHS has no twice-differentiable at $\theta=0 $ solution. Let us put $N=3,u(\theta)\approx a_0+a_1\theta+a_2\theta^2,\sin(\theta)\approx\theta,\cos(\theta)\approx 1-\theta^2/2.$ Then the LHS is $\approx \frac{\left(1-\frac{\theta^{2}}{2}\right) \left(2 \theta  \mathit{a_2}+\mathit{a_1}\right)+2 \theta  \mathit{a_2}}{\theta}$. Maple code to this end
N := 3:eval(diff(sin(theta)^(N - 2)*diff(u(theta), theta), theta)/
sin(theta)^(N - 2) , {cos(theta) = 1 - theta^2/2, sin(theta) = theta,
u(theta) = a2*theta^2 + a1*theta + a0});

This implies $a_1=0$. Then the LHS is $\approx -\mathit{a_2} \theta^{2}+4 \mathit{a_2}$, whehereas the RHS is $\approx {\mathrm e}^{\mathit{a_0}}+{\mathrm e}^{\mathit{a_0}} \mathit{a_2} \theta^{2} $. Therefore $a_2>0$ and the signs of $-\mathit{a_2}$ and $e^{a_0}a_2$ differ.

Thank you for your answer! Sorry for my careless omission, I want to ask about the case when $f$ is nonlinear such as
$
f(u)=e^u .
$

@ElioLi: See the addition to my answer.

I think I can modify the RHS as $c-e^u$ where $c$ is positive. As a student know less numerical things, I was always wondering, for this kind of nonlinear ode, what can numerical method do? could maple directly give a solution if I give a boundary condition?

@ElioLi: I can say nothing, not seeing those BC.
